# UITableView for a list of Controls

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to understand when one should/should not use a UITableView.

I do know, if there is a table of information UITableView would be the perfect fit. But what if there are rows of "controls" ?

See the image below.

[image]

What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of using a UITableView to achieve layout above?

What alternatives to a UITableView exist for achieving such a layout?

Comment: There is no one answer to this question. You could do it either way, and which is better is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @DuncanC The question has been edited to remove the subjective opinion portion, perhaps it should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to the question of how many controls/rows you will have and what they represent.

**Dynamic Number of Controls Based on Model**

A tableview is the perfect solution. The complications with having controls in a table view cell that is dynamically generated:

1) You cannot add IBActions for controls in table view cells. You will need to add a target/action to each control when the cell is generated.

2) Your action method will need a way to determine which element in your model the cell is displaying when selected (since cells are reused, controls will correspond to many model objects). To do this you need the index path in your model corresponding to the selected control. This can be done as follows (assuming a button but should work for any control):

Determine the control's position in the tableview:

`let buttonPosition = button.convertPoint(.zero, toView: tableView)`

Find the index path

`let indexPath = self.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)`

Then query your model for the object at the index path and respond accordingly.

**Finite Number of Controls**

The above is needlessly complex if you have a finite and known number of controls at runtime. In that case the above layout can be easily achieved with a UIStackView.

See [StackView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/)

Comment: I would also add the overall size as a factor.  A UITableView has memory advantages when you have a list of controls that will be longer than the screen can display.  iOS will only render / build cells that are on screen and will also re-use existing cells as the scroll off the screen.  This is very memory efficient and can really help versus a large UIScrollView with fixed content. If you only have 2 or 3 items, you could go even more simple and just build out the controls in a UIView. Less overhead than the UITableView / UIStackView, but also less flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Having controls in tableViews is perfectly fine.

You may want to know that tableviews have scrollable content and selectable cells, so your interactions will be slightly different than if you directly put your controls in a view.

Row selection and bouncing bounds can be annoying, as well as the delayed tap while touching inside a scroll view.

But if you need your controls to be dynamically shown depending on your settings, it can be done with the tableview data source or delegate methods.